# How do I connect between firebase and visual studio?

Tags: firebase, xamarin

I am currently making an app project, in which I have a large usage of databases and the typical platforms on visual studio, aren't enough for my needs. I am trying to make interactions between databases and found that firebase will be useful for that. Most of the instructions I found, for firebase conecction with apps, are for android studio, and I am working with xamarin. The answers I did find for xamarin platform, just didn't work for me, not sure why. I am quit desprate and need some help in connecting the two, or maybe a suggestion for a different kind of database, which will answer my needs.
Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: "just didn't work for me, not sure why" is not a good description of the problem.  What specifically did you try and what specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: If you want to work with Firebase database in xamarin.forms project,you could refer to [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/)

Comment: Sorry for the dumb description, I just wrote it out of frustration. The thing is I've tried to download a nuget package named :" Xamarin.Firebase.Database" , that's suppoesd to help me interact with the firebase project, and when I downloaded it I received an error saying the package isn't copatible with the monoandroid version i have, should I download a newer version of visual studio?

Comment: you could refer the error message, which version of monoandroid version it need,then change to the correct version